# Get User Photo, Name &Title of an office 365 group using SPfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, ms-graph-client

I am trying get the user details i.e. UserName, Title and Profile picture of users that belong to a office 365 distribution group.

I tried this [code sample](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph), but I get an undefined error:

> `msGraphClientFactory` is undefined.

```
export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {
  public render(): void {
    // ...

    this.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        // use MSGraphClient here
      });
  }
  // ...
}
```

Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong or suggest an alternative to get the groups members and their user profile info like photo, name an title?

Answer (score 0):

Which version you're using?

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph#msgraphclient-overview),

> **MSGraphClient** is a new HTTP client introduced in **SharePoint Framework v1.6.0** that simplifies connecting to the Microsoft Graph inside SharePoint Framework solutions.

I did test in my local environment with SharePoint Framework v1.8.2 and there is no such error.

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee, Can you share your solution on github , so that I can compare it with my solution.